# Why is comparing an array and a number so slow in JavaScript? What is it doing?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I accidentally compared a large array and a number with `<`, and JavaScript locked up for over 5 seconds. What is the expected behavior of this comparison? Is it iterating over the whole array? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_operator) didn't clarify the situation.

As a concrete example, this code snippet takes over 5 seconds to print `done`:

```js
var m = [];
m[268435461] = -1;
console.log('start');
if (m < 0) { }
console.log('done');
```

Comment: You are assigning the 268435461th entry in a sparse array the value -1 - is that is what you wanted to do?

Comment: You've created a sparse array, which is stored differently from regular arrays to be more memory efficient.  They're also slower.

Comment: The comparison is slow because `m` is first coerced to a (huge) string. `let x = []; x[3] = -1; '' + x` gives `,,,-1`. Your `m` is coerced to 268435461 commas followed by -1. At least on modern Chrome, creating a sparse array takes a few milliseconds, and is **not** the reason your example is slow.

Comment: Why would it coerce it to a string instead of a number?

Comment: Long story short, (loosely) comparing an object to a number invokes the [`ToPrimitive`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toprimitive) procedure, which invokes `valueOf`, doesn't get back a primitive, and invokes `toString`.

Comment: Looks like Igor already covered that.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes, I have a large sparse array. The comparison is what I did by accident.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript "arrays" (those with `Array` prototype, not typed arrays), are just objects, therefore this

```
var m = [];
m[268435461] = -1;
```

is exactly the same as

```
var m = {
    "268435461": -1
}
```

except that in the first case, `m` has the `Array` prototype and a special `length` property.

However, methods defined in `Array.prototype` (like `forEach` or `join`) are trying to hide that fact and "emulate" sequential arrays, as they exist in other languages. When iterating their "this" array, these methods take  its `length` property, increase the loop counter from `0` upto `length-1` and do something with the value under the key `String(i)` (or `undefined` if there's no such key)

```
// built-in js array iteration algorithm

for (let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
     if (this.hasOwnProperty(String(i))
         do_something_with(this[String(i)])
     else
         do_something_with(undefined)
```

Now, `length` of an array is not a number of elements in it, as the name might suggest, but rather the max numeric value of its keys + 1, so in your case, `length` will be `268435462` (check it!)

When you do `m < 0`, that is, compare a non-number to a number, JS converts them both to strings, and `Array.toString` invokes `Array.join`, which, in turn, uses the above loop to convert elements to strings and insert a comma in between:

```
// built-in js Array.join algorithm

target = '';

for (let i = 0; i < this.length - 1; i++) {
    let element = this[String(i)]

    if(element !== undefined)
        target += element.toString()

    target += ','
}
```

Illustration:

```js
m  = [];
m[50] = 1;
console.log(m.join())
```

This involves lots of memory allocations, and that's what is causing the delay.

(After some more testing, the allocation are not the deciding factor here,  "hollow" loops will cause the same slowdown:

```js
console.time('small-init')
var m = [];
m[1] = -1;
console.timeEnd('small-init')

console.time('small-loop')
m.forEach(x => null)
console.timeEnd('small-loop')

console.time('big-init')
var m = [];
m[1e8] = -1;
console.timeEnd('big-init')

console.time('big-loop')
m.forEach(x => null);
console.timeEnd('big-loop')
```

That being said, I don't think modern JS engines are *that* silly, and implement iterations exactly as described above. They do have array-specific optimizations in place, but these optimizations are targeted at "good" sequential arrays, and not at bizarre edge cases like this. Bottom line: don't do that!

Comment: Arrays are `Vectors` or `ArrayList`s exactly like they exist in other languages. Sure, JS has a unified way of accessing elements in the same way as properties, but I wouldn't say that JS aren't "sequential". Imo you should just drop the first part of your answer, it doesn't seem relevant to the question.

Comment: @Bergi: last time I checked, Ecma spec didn't mention Vectors or ArrayLists, it does, however, say that "A[rrays]'s essential internal methods... [are] the default ordinary object definitions"

Comment: The ECMA spec doesn't detail memory layout of objects and arrays at all, so it's irrelevant. In every JS engine implementation I've encountered so far, arrays and objects were handled very differently though.

Comment: @Bergi: so, why exactly is this code slow? An array optimization should have kicked in and realized that there's only one element in the array, not a gazillion...

Comment: It probably did realise that there are no elements in the array. But as you correctly explained, it still has to build a 268435463-character string, which is the slow thing.

Comment: @Bergi: ok, how about https://jsfiddle.net/fbv761uc/ ? All I do is `x.forEach(null)` - no allocations involved, but the "big" array is still very slow.

Comment: I'm not contesting that large arrays are slow (regardless whether sparse or not). I just think that "arrays are plain objects" is both misleading and irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @georg JS tried to convert both sides of the `>` to types that can actually be compared, so in this case, it converts both sides to stringss, and `m.toString()` when there are 268,435,461 elements (268,435,460 are `undefined`) will need to allocate about half a gig of RAM just to hold the resulting string. That's going to take a few seconds.

Comment: @Bergi: according to the spec, arrays are objects. How they are actually implemented in the respective engine's C++ code, is secondary and subject to change. Even as a metaphor, that seems to explain things very well, in particular, why it's not the assignment line, that causes the OP's problems (no allocation of gazillion elements happens), but the comparison line (where gazillion loops are actually being made).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: as I tried to explain (and with what Bergi disagrees) there are actually no 268,435,461 elements in this array - just one.

Comment: I don't disagree that the array in the question is sparse, has only one element and takes little memory. I just think that the phrasing "*Javascript "arrays" are just objects, […] is exactly the same as […] [array] methods [...] are trying to hide that fact and "emulate" sequential arrays, as they exist in other languages.*" is highly misleading (if not plain wrong) and irrelevant.

Comment: On a true, spec-wise, technical note, Arrays are Objects, not "vectors" or "arraylists" or "dictionaries" or any other term not in the spec. On a JS Engine _implementation_ level, the fact that they're modelled as specific C++ or Rust etc. datatypes is mostly irrelevant to this discussion. Arrays, as far as JS is concerned, are a more specific type of Object, with an Array prototype and special handling around numeric property names. Even if the underlying native code, to which no one has access at runtime, uses some kind of indexed list primitive.